# Registration And Login with facebook

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress

In the registration page, I'm giving the user the option to fill most of the fields by making him login to my website with facebook so that I can have access to his data, then he should fill some other fields and then register to my website.

On the login page, users have the option to login with a username and password or login with the facebook accounts they used to register before.

On the login page I have this code:

```
if ($user){
    try {
        $loggedin= true;
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');

        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
                                  array(
                                    'scope' => 'publish_stream,read_friendlists,email'
                                  )
                            );

        if(email_exists($user_profile['email'])){
            $user = get_user_by('email', $user_profile['email']);
            wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->id );
            wp_redirect( site_url() ); exit;
        }else{
            wp_redirect( site_url('/register/') ); exit;
        }

    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
                                  array(
                                    'scope' => 'publish_stream,read_friendlists,email'
                                  )
                            ); 
        $loggedin= false;
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
    }
}else{
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
                                  array(
                                    'scope' => 'publish_stream,read_friendlists,email'
                                  )
                            );
    $loggedin= false;
}
```

So if the user is logged in with facebook, the code checks if he is a member, and if so he's authenticated and redirected to the home page, if the email doesn't exist he should be redirected to the registration page.

The problem is that if a user logged in with facebook in the registration page, the login page code will recognize him as a logged in user and will give him access if he's a member or redirect him if  he's not a member, but what if a user would like to login with another account?

What I need to do is to terminate the access token in the login page so that he should re-login with his facebook account. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this page http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

> **Logging the user out of Facebook**
>
> You can programmatically log the user out of Facebook by redirecting
>   the user to 
>   https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=YOUR_REDIRECT_URL&access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN
>
> The URL supplied in the next parameter must be a URL with the same base domain
>   as your application as defined in your app's settings.
>
> You can also log the user out of Facebook on the client-side using the
>   Javascript SDK by calling `FB.logout()`.